# How to Hyperlink a Single word in a string to another area of the Android App

Tags: android, string, hyperlink

I am writing an app for android and i am trying to have part of the string hyperlinked to another page within the app, but am struggling as to how to do it.

I have managed to get it to work with a whole textview like this:

```
TextView txtVirus = (TextView) findViewById(R.glossaryMalwareID.txtVirus);      
txtVirus.setText(Html.fromHtml("<U>Computer Virus<U>"));        
txtVirus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent ("com.digitalsecurity.app.GLOSSARYVIRUS"));
        }
    });
```

however this means that the string has to be on a compleatly new line (or so i believe).

What i would like is to be able to do as the notes in the code below show:

```
        TextView txtVirus = (TextView) findViewById(R.glossaryMalwareID.virusmain);     
    txtVirus.setText(Html.fromHtml("<br>" +
            "A Computer Virus is a small peice of " +
            "Software" +//i want the word 'software' hyperlinked to another page in my program
            "so on and so on"));
```

Comment: I think you'll have to have them on a separate TextViews (or for the more complicated way- messing around with the coordinate of the touch) .. just tide them up nicely using xml and it wont appear on another row..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after 4 hours of searching and tweaking i have the answer:

```
TextView txtVirus = (TextView) findViewById(R.glossaryMalwareID.virusmain);

    // this is the text we'll be operating on
    SpannableString text = new SpannableString("A Computer Virus is a small peice of Software. to make this easier to");

    //stops it from flickering to another colour when string is pressed.
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, 69, 0);

    // make "Software" (characters 37 to 45) 
    //runs when clickableSpan is pressed
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent ("com.digitalsecurity.app.MALWAREHOWTOPROTECT"));
        }
    };
    //this is what calls the method
    text.setSpan(clickableSpan, 37, 45, 0);
    //underlines it
    text.setSpan(new URLSpan(""), 37, 45, 0);
    //turns it blue
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 37, 45, 0);


    txtVirus.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    // shove our styled text into the TextView
    txtVirus.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

i got the help from here which also has other rather helpfull formatting options:

http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring

i hope it helps someone else who needs the same

Answer (score 0):

for your TextView if the link is displayed your `Textview` is look like:

```
TextView txtVirus = (TextView) findViewById(R.glossaryMalwareID.virusmain);
txtVirus .setText("A Computer Virus is a small peice of " +
        "Software" + just write down your link automatically converted to URL 
        "so on and so on);
Linkify.addLinks(noteView, Linkify.ALL);
```

Read this [LINKY FY FOR ANDROID](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/wikinotes-linkify.html)

let me know if you have any query..